# Total spin for the ground state of the Kitaev honeycomb model is 0?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, symmetry, spin-models

We consider the Kitaev honeycomb model:
\begin{align}
H=\sum_{\langle ij\rangle_{\mu}}J_{\mu}S^{\mu}_iS^{\mu}_j.
\end{align}
If $J \equiv J_x=J_y=J_z$, the Hamiltonian can be written in
\begin{align}
H=J\sum_{\langle ij\rangle_{\mu}} S^{\mu}_iS^{\mu}_j.
\end{align}
Then, from Lieb's theorem, can we conclude the ground state is unique and the total spin $S=0$ where $(\sum_i \boldsymbol{S}_i)^2=S(S+1)$?

Comment: The Hamiltonian breaks the SO(3) spin rotation symmetry, so it is meaningless to ask what is the total spin.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I realized my mistake and now I understand.